# Ubuntu "find" command for count of files in each directory unexpected count

Tags: ubuntu, find

I am using the find command to give me a list of the number of files in each directory and sub-directories. This is the command

```
find . -maxdepth 100 -mindepth 2 -type f -printf "%h\0" | uniq -zc | tr '\0' '\n'
```

However, I am getting repeated output. For example,

```
 20 ./WDE/J/P
  2 ./WDE/J/P/Base47
 23 ./WDE/J/P/Base47/b
 12 ./WDE/J/P/Base47
 72 ./WDE/J/P/Base47/c
 46 ./WDE/J/P/Base47
  7 ./WDE/J/P
 23 ./WDE/J/P/z
 23 ./WDE/J/P
```

Directory P has 2 sub-directories and 50 files. They are grouped as 20 7 23 files which does add up to 50. Base47 has 2 directories and 60 files. The counts for b, c and z are correct. I don't know why the 50 and 60 files have been divided into different lines. Within the J tree there are no hidden files or file names with special characters or spaces. But there are files with spaces etc. on the WDE drive. I have tried other 'find' formats but this is the only one that does not produce an error such as "No such file or directory" or "permission denied" even though I am using sudo.

Thank you.

Comment: Yes this modified code works. Thank you. I now need to combine and analyse the text output groupings with the directory size details using "du --apparent-size". Should I post any questions to this forum or is there another recommended forum?

Answer (score 1):

This means `find` generated a sequence where entries for `./WDE/J/P/Base47` did not form a single block of lines, `./WDE/J/P/Base47/b` and `./WDE/J/P/Base47/c` cut in. Similarly for `./WDE/J/P`: other lines cut in.

You need to `sort` before `uniq`. Your command modified:

```
find . -maxdepth 100 -mindepth 2 -type f -printf "%h\0" | sort -z | uniq -zc | tr '\0' '\n'
```

Comment: `sort -u` doesn't make it possible to `uniq -c`. `sort | uniq -c` is the right solution.

Comment: @choroba True. Thank you.

Comment: I tried the sort | uniq combination but it returned exactly the same results as my original attempt.

Comment: @ubnewb Was is `sort -z`?

Comment: I tried with sort and no options, and with sort -z.  Both produced a huge file with one line per file, but without any counts.

Comment: @ubnewb To be super clear I included a modified command based on your original command. Please confirm it doesn't work for you.